# Ignore non-numeric characters in numbers for DataTables sort

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm creating a custom sort plugin for DataTables which will sort numeric columns which contain non-numeric rows as well. I got the part where it puts the 'N/A' rows at the bottom but cannot seem to figure out, how to make it ignore the commas in the numbers.

For example:

$12,443.00
362,123,231
N/A
N/A
null
34,242.42
23,234
null

The code below manages to ignore everything except for the commas in the numbers.

Code:

```
function numeric_sort(a, b, high) {
    var reg = /[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;
    a = a.match(reg);
    a = a !== null ? parseFloat(a[0]) : high;
    b = b.match(reg);
    b = b !== null ? parseFloat(b[0]) : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
}

jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "numeric-empty-bottom-asc": function (a, b) {
        return numeric_sort(a, b, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    },
    "numeric-empty-bottom-desc": function (a, b) {
        return numeric_sort(a, b, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) * -1;
    }
} );
```

I got the code from: http://jsfiddle.net/6qmkY/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please make a pull request if you find some useful corrections to the original plugin https://github.com/davidkonrad/datatables-sort-numbers-ignore-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `replace()` to remove commas.

```
function sortNumbersIgnoreText(a, b, high) {
    var reg = /[+-]?((\d+(\.\d*)?)|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?/;    
    a = a.replace(/,/g, '');
    a = a.match(reg);      
    a = a !== null ? parseFloat(a[0]) : high;
    b = b.replace(/,/g, '');
    b = b.match(reg);    
    b = b !== null ? parseFloat(b[0]) : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));    
}
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qmkY/80/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: a.replace(',', ''); only replaced the first comma. Used a.replace(/[, ]+/g, "").trim(); instead and it replaced all the commas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KumaranS, you're absolutely right, corrected the code.

Answer (score -1):

You could replace all non numeric chars including commas (excluding the decimal).

```
function sortNumbersIgnoreText(a, b, high) {
    a = a.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    a = (a !== null && a !== '') ? parseFloat(a) : high;
    b = b.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    b = (b !== null && b !== '') ? parseFloat(b) : high;
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));    
}
```